# User Defined Interrupt

Tags: python

In python, I am running an kind of indefinite loop wherein process sleeps for predefined time
and then it pops up asking for the input. here's the pseudo code what i am trying

```
while(1):
  time.sleep(3600) //wait for one hour


  pop_up_and_ask_for_input
```

while i am able to do the above, i want one more additional requirement, whenever as a user i want to interrupt and provide input myself. Program should take the input and continue from where it left off. Please help me to do the later part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import your modules, as a best practice in Python:

```
import time
import sys
```

You need a data structure in which to capture the inputs, I'll use a list:

```
inputs = []
```

In Python 2, it's better to use raw_input than input,

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    input = raw_input
```

And factor out reusable code so you don't have to write it twice:

```
def user_input():
    user_in = input('\nplease give your input (Ctrl+C to break): ') # pop_up_and_ask_for_input
    if user_in:
         inputs.append(user_in)
```

To capture a keyboard interrupt (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), you put the loop in a try except block and perform the input capture function there as well.

```
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(3600) # wait for one hour
        user_input()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # stop and get input now
        try:
            user_input()
        except KeyboardInterrupt: # graciously leave loop if another interrupt
            break
```

How this works in an interactive session:

```
^C
please give your input (Ctrl+C to break): foo
^C
please give your input (Ctrl+C to break): bar
^C
please give your input (Ctrl+C to break): >>> 

>>> print(inputs)
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Aaron's answer has the problem that if the user hits Control-C in response to the input prompt she is asked again for input. This version terminates the loop immediately under those conditions, and simply terminates the sleep if no prompt has yet been presented.

```
import time
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(3600)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print  # print newline to get back to col 1
    try:
        in_string = raw_input("Enter hourly input:")
        # process the input
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # graciously leave the loop if another interrupt
        break
```

Comment: I think you're confusing my answer with the other one.